# Evaluating $\oint_{\gamma(t)} \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^3}dz$ where $\gamma(t)$ is the circle with radius $2$ centered at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have to evaluate the following integral $\oint_{\gamma(t)} \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^3}dz$ where $\gamma(t)$ is the circle with radius $2$ centered at $z=0$.

I know that $\int f(z)dz = \int f(\gamma(t))\dot{\gamma}(t)dt$ and I know that the path for a circle with radius $2$ around $z = 0$ is $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$. Then, $\dot{\gamma}(t) = 2ie^{it}$. Inserting this into the integral I get $\oint_{\gamma(t)} \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^3}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{2e^{it}}}{{(2e^{it} + 1})^3} 2ie^{it}dt$. For solving it, I can make the substitution $u = 2e^{it} ; \ dt = \frac{du}{2ie^{it}} = \frac{du}{iu}$ and then I get $\int \frac{{e^{u}}}{(u + 1)^3}\frac{iu}{iu}du = \int \frac{{e^{u}}}{(u + 1)^3} du$.

But here I'm stuck.

1. Did I got it right up to the last integral with the substitution?
2. Any tips for how to continue?

Comment: It's not impossible to continue with your method, however you will end up with a lot of antiderivatives that will look something like $\arctan(k \tan t)$. Like the answer has stated, it is easier to use complex analysis theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$Unfortunately, the majority of complex integrals (or just the majority of *all* integrals) that can be easily written down can't be easily found if you only use techniques of Riemann integration. In general, it is good advice to completely avoid substitutions $z=\gamma(t)$! Complex analysis has produced many beautiful theorems involving integration of complex contours.

The one I will present to you now is the [Cauchy Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

> $$f^{(n)}(s)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-s)^{n+1}}\,\d z$$

If $f$ is a holomorphic function in some neighbourhood of $s\in\Bbb C$, and $\gamma$ is a **closed** contour that is contained in this neighbourhood which also winds counterclockwise - once - about the point $s$.

Here, $s=-1$ and the circle of radius $2$ - I assume a counterclockwise winding - is a contour of the correct type as it encloses $-1$. $f(z)=e^z$ is of course holomorphic in this neighbourhood of $-1$. It follows that: $$\frac{\d^2}{\d z^2}[e^z]\Big |_{z=-1}=\frac{2!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{(z+1)^3}\,\d z$$But that just means to say your integral equals $\frac{\pi i}{e}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The Cauchy formula is really helpful!

Comment: @FShirke I have one more question. If I have $\oint_{\gamma(t)} \frac{z}{(z+1)(z+3)}dz$ where $\gamma(t)$ is a square with corners $2 \pm i $ and $2 \mp i $. Can I perform a partial fraction decomposition, from which i get $\oint_{\gamma(t)} \frac{3}{2(z+3} - \frac{1}{2(z+1)}dz$ and then split the integral into 2 integrals and apply for each the Cauchy Integral Formula?

Comment: @syphracos Yes you can. However, partial fractions aren’t always necessary. You will eventually learn the residue theorem - the ‘ultimate’ partial fraction technique, in essence - but also note that $-3$ is not enclosed by this contour. Thus you can treat $z/(z+3)$ as your holomorphic $f(z)$ and apply the standard integral formula

Comment: @FShirke thanks again! If I understand it correctly, $\frac{z}{z+3}$ is holomorphic inside the square exactly because the point $z_0 = -3$ is OUTSIDE this square, i.e. the pole of $\frac{z}{z+3}$ is outside the square?

Comment: @syphracos Yes.  $z\mapsto z/(z+3)$ is a meromorphic function with only one singularity, at $z=-3$. It is holomorphic on the interior of any contour *not* enclosing $-3$.

Comment: Okay, now I understand it. Sorry if I bother You too much, but do you maybe have any tips for the following problem: I have the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x) = \frac{n!}{2^n} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x^2 - 1)^n$ and have to show/derive the integral form $ P_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} (x + \sqrt (1-x^2) \cos t)^n dt $  for $ |x| < 1$   by using the derivative form as a complex integral

Comment: so as I understand it, I get $P_n (x) = \frac{1}{n!2^n} \int \frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2 - 1)^n dz$. I'm not sure if this is correct and how to proceed further?

Comment: @syphracos Sorry, I don't know anything about the Legendre polynomials. That seems like it would be a good question to ask in a separate MSE post

Comment: no probs. Thanks for all the help! :)